# attached fires when component is on page, but i cant dom process because it isnt rendered?

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have a web component which leverages some template repeaters.  I noticed that even though the item is attached to the page, it isnt rendered.  Since it isnt rendered, the template repeater isnt processed.

Is there any sort of on render, or paint function which is called when the component is actually drawn?

I was doing some component queries which were related to the template dom-repeater content.  It doesnt find the classes because it doesnt stamp out the info.

How would i go about the "on Render" ?

Right now i was doing something like:

```
@property List<Map> knownList = [{"name":"Bob"},{"name":"Jake"},{"name":"Larry"}];

attached(){
  toBinaryString();
}

String toBinaryString(){
  String binaryString = "";
  document.getElementsByClassName("selected").forEach((HtmlElement ele){
    print("Fired");
    binaryString += "1";
  });
  print("Result diagnostics/ Length: ${binaryString.length} isValid: ${binaryString.length==(CONST_PER_DAY * 7)}");
  return binaryString;
}
```

my Html is something simple like:

```
<dom-module id="my-test">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeater" items="{{knownList}}">
      <div class="selected">{{item.name}}</div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

and attached is fired when the page loads, as this item is in fact added to the page, but because of it not being rendered I cant do any sort of dom related processing.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `ready() {...}` instead of `attached() { ... }`? See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/registration-and-lifecycle

Comment: I did, and i noticed that it was firing after on create, but before on attached.  It seems that attached comes later in the life cycle so i thought that attached might be the best course of action.  Im just not sure what the different connotations of Attached vs Ready are, as the items would still not be rendered when doing ready.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/registration-and-lifecycle#ready-callback-and-local-dom-initialization

> The ready callback is called when an element's local DOM is ready.
>
> It is called after the element's template has been stamped and all elements inside the element's local DOM have been configured (with values bound from parents, deserialized attributes, or else default values) and had their ready method called.

Comment: bizarre.  I will take a second look at this then.  There may be some outler which neither you or nor i know of, which would need to be addressed.  Ill take another look though and see what i can do around that being leveraged.  If i can get it working, I will inform you of specific code, how i did it, and then give you the points and the answer. :)

Comment: You should find your answer using async call within attached, as documented in the documentation Gunter gave you a link to.